# server.listen callback function in Typescript and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, server

I don't understand why the codes below doesn't work in typescript.
(In my past javascript code, it works!!)

```
http.createServer(app).listen(port, (err) => {
    # Do something
});
```

While this works,(without parameter to callback function)

```
http.createServer(app).listen(port, () => {
    # Do something
});
```

Where can I find "official" document for the format of this callback function??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand why the codes below doesn't work in typescript.

TypeScript is actually correct, the callback of `.listen` isn't actually ever called with an `Error`.

The thing you're `listen`ing is an express server, it inherits its `.listen` from the `net` (TCP) server it builds on which in turn just listens to the [`listening`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/net.js#L1380) event which [never actually emits an error](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/net.js#L1324).

The way to listen to an error would be to do

```js
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.on('error', (e) => {
  // Handle Error
});
server.listen(port, () => {
  // do whatever
});
```

> Where can I find "official" document for the format of this callback function??

For HTTP it's documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen), indicating it inherits from `net`'s server documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen).

All the examples use `listen` without an argument in the docs as well.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but still remain things. Why then the second code(with err parameter) works in Javascript? Is it changed? And even docs doesn't tell us explicitly that the callback function doesn't have any parameter, We just can know by assuming that.

Comment: It doesn't work with JavaScript, the `err` parameter is never passed. JavaScript just allows calling/passing functions with extra parameters.

Comment: Now, I get it. That means err parameter is allowed in JavaScript, but never used, right? Thank you very much. Still couldn't find explicit detail format of callback, but satisfied.

Comment: I literally left a link to where it's defined in the Node.js source code :]